# Set Table width and separate some rows

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to make the table take the line width of the paper but I don't know how to do this. I want it to look like this:

[image: this]

However, it's appearing like this:

[image: this]

This is the script I used:

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rlrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{E}} & \textbf{A} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{B}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{C}} \\
    \midrule
          & \textbf{q} & 0     & 0 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{X}} & \textbf{w} & 0     & 0 \\
          & \textbf{e} & 0     & 0 \\
          & \textbf{r} & 0     & 0 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Y}} & \textbf{t} & 0     & 0 \\
          & \textbf{y} & 0     & 0 \\
          & \textbf{u} & 0     & 0 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Z}} & \textbf{i} & 0     & 0 \\
          & \textbf{o} & 0     & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table*}%
```

Comment: Can you space things out by using `p{width}` as your column specifier?  Like http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62718/47522 ?

Comment: Additional `\midrule`s can be used after the appropriate `\\\` to add more separation lines...

Comment: I want to stretch the table to be automatically have the linewidth

Comment: You can use `p{\dimexpr 0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}` as specified in the link I mentioned earlier. Each column will be equally spaced, but it will come out to `\linewidth` width.

Comment: Looks like it is solved with this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44802/47522