# Table over only part of a page?

Tags: tables

I'm currently trying to create a table which has a specific width (table and content itself). After quite a few attempts I found a working solution but my question here is: Is this the way to go or is there any better way there?

```
\begin{tabular}{llp{3in}}
 1 & 2 & 3 this is really long \\
 4 & 5 & 6 this is really long this is really long\\
 7 & 8 & 9 this is really long this is really long this is really long\\
 10&11 & 12 this is really long this is really long this is really long this is really long\\
\end{tabular}
```

where the table is widthwise only as broad as for example half of the page

Comment: Your current example will produce a table that is only as wide as its content. So the answer is "Yes"... I guess?

Comment: tnx was an error on my part reformulateed it three times and forgot to remove the as broad as the content part^^

Comment: For this the most convenient package is [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). See [Automatically stretch table to evenly fill horizontal space?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44795/5764)

Comment: I tried that one out but had the problem that even though the table line itself ended for example after 3 inches the text still went to textwidth

Comment: How about providing what you've tried as part of the question?

Comment: do you mean you want the body text to wrap around the table? (wrapfig package if you do mean that) otherwise I can't guess what you mean

Comment: I want the whole table (inlcuding the text within) to take up only 1/3 of the page as example. found a possibility will modify question there.

Answer (score 7):

You can use either a `tabular*` or a `tabularx` environment to create a table with a prespecified width of, say `0.5\textwidth`.

As the screenshot below demonstrates, the looks of the `tabular*` and `tabularx` environments are quite different even though the overall widths are the same (by construction!). `tabular*` works by expanding the intercolumn whitespace, whereas `tabularx` works by expanding the widths of the columns (while keeping the intercolumn whitespace to `2\tabcolsep`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document} 
\hrule  %% just to demonstate the overall width of the text block
\medskip
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 10&11 & 12\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{tabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll} %% note "@{\extracolsep{\fill}}"
\hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 10&11 & 12\\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{XXX}  % note: "X" instead of "l"
\hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 10&11 & 12\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: I just noticed that you've udpated the table code, and that the updated table's third column now contains text that needs to spread overall several rows. In order to get the updated table to occupy a width of `0.5\textwidth`, I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment and use a modified form of that package's `X` column type instead of the current `p{3in}` column. I recommend you use a modified `X` column type because it's usually better to typeset a narrow column of text in ragged-right mode rather than in fully-justified mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for tabularx environment
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for \RaggedRight macro
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % set contents of "Y" ragged-right
\begin{document}
\hrule  %% just to demonstrate width of text block
\medskip
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{llY}
\hline
 1 & 2 & 3 this is really long \\
 4 & 5 & 6 this is really long this is really long\\
 7 & 8 & 9 this is really long this is really long this is really long\\
 10&11 & 12 this is really long this is really long this is really long this is really long\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```